# Mac: How can I have Adium reindex the chat logs for searching through the Chat Transcript Viewer window?

Tags: mac, search, adium

In Adium, When I go to the Chat Transcript Viewer window to search for stuff in the chat logs, it not always finds what I want.

Is there an index file that I can delete to have it reindex the logs? Or does it use spotlight in the underpinnings?

Where would said file be?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an option under "File"->"Import" named "Reindex Adium Logs".

That does the trick.

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

1. Quit Adium
2. Remove `/Users/<your user name>/Library/Caches/Adium/Default`
3. Relaunch Adium

See more at http://trac.adium.im/ticket/7818

Answer (score 1):

I added a comment to the bottom of the page that Doug Harris linked to. Using Snow Leopard I ended up deleting the entire ~/Library/Caches/Adium folder because deleting just the specififed folder did not work.